# React Formik form - remember values onChange and reset them on submit

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using `Formik` to create form in my react app. There are few tabs on view, and all of them contain same form (form with same fields). I want some fields to be remembered while user switches tabs. What came to my mind is to save values into `Redux` on field `onChange` event but according to `Formik` documentation it is not recommended to save `Formik values` into `Redux state`.
Also, on form submit, I want these values to be cleared/reset. What would be the best approcah?

Answer (score 1):

when switching tabs you can pass `initialValues` to the new form.

- you can store it in Redux and provide the stored data to `initialValues`
- you can store it in upper state and provide the stored data to `initialValues`

The trick is do not store actual values but create at runtime an object to use as `initialValues`

Comment: I have `initialValues` already, and it is not new form on switching tabs, but the same one (same component). Initial values are empty of course. For example, there is `description` field on form, and if I change it on one tab, I want that value be remembered if I switch tab. Also, on form submit, I want it to be cleared.

Comment: Before switching tab copy the values you need in a object, store in any state (redux, local state) and then provide it to the initialValues of the next tab